# Как добавить своё приложение в контекстное меню файлового менеджера Linux и Windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows

Например, есть Visual Studio Code, который при установке предлагает добавить себя в контекстное меню. Потом файлы можно открывать в файловом менеджере с помощью VSC через контекстное меню. У меня есть простенькое приложение, написанное на Python 3. Я вызываю его так:

```
$ python3 encdec e text.txt output.ena // Ключ "e" - "encode"
$ python3 encdec d output.ena decoded.txt // Ключ "d" - "decode"
```

Я бы хотел, чтобы я мог делать это с помощью контекстного меню. Условно - 
 кнопки "Encode with encdec" и "Decode with encdec". Важно, чтобы можно было сделать это как на Windows, так и на Linux.

В интернете не нашёл, как такое сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я использую обычные "открыть с помощью" вместо этих меню.

## Windows

в реестре `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/shellex/ContextMenuHandlers` и `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/shell/...`. В первом случае нужен COM-сервер специального вида, во втором можно запускать командой.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   .myp-ms
      (Default) = MyProgram.1
      MyProgram.1
         (Default) = My Program Application
         Shell
            (Default) = doit
            doit
               (Default) = &Do It
               command
                  (Default) = c:\MyDir\MyProgram.exe /d "%1"
            open
               command
                  (Default) = c:\MyDir\MyProgram.exe /d "%1"
            print
               command
                  (Default) = c:\MyDir\MyProgram.exe /p "%1"
            printto
               command
                  (Default) = c:\MyDir\MyProgram.exe /p "%1" "%2"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/context-menu-handlers

## Linux

тоже в реестре gconf или dconf в зависимости от версии. В KDE не знаю, в легких менеджерах скорее всего этой функции нет.

Nautilus через nautilus-actions. Сейчас он переименован в `filemanager-actions` (c 19ого года), но в репозиториях stretch/bionic: nautilus-actions, caja-actions и где-то есть nemo-actions.

Програмка настраивается мышкой.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На freedesktop.org описаны Actions, которые можно указать в файле .desktop, но они видимо нигде нормально не поддерживаются.

Comment: Для Windows написано неправильно. Во-первых, вы ключ реестра указали с ошибкой, а во-вторых, вы так изящно опустили незначительную деталь что именно в этом ключе должно указываться. А указывается там CLSID хендлера, то есть COM-сервер специального вида, а не какие-то имена приблуд на Питоне. В общем, удалили бы вы эту часть ответа.

Comment: @freim ответ можно улучшить

Comment: @freim вот рядом есть интересный раздел.

Comment: Да, совсем другое дело.  :)